# How to speed up load images of html in ionic?

Tags: image, ionic2, ionic3, height, width

I need to know can I compressed or reduce the size of image in case I display it in small value of width and height?

For example: I have images with more than 2500×2500px. so, when I try to load more than 12 to 20 images together its take a long time!

**Note**: I already changed theirs width and height to  300×300px but the problem still not solved

So, any simple solution ?

Comment: I think you should implement `Lazy Loading`.

Answer (score 0):

Which format of image you are using?
Google recommend webp format, it'll allow to compress size of image without much compromise on quality of it
https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/

Comment: Images format is jpg, jpeg, gif, png.. users uploads the images so this solution will not work.

Comment: I assume you are converting their width and height on server, because if you convert in js(client) code, then it still have to fetch full size image from server and show to the client only 300x300px